# How to convert a `<tkinter.PhotoImage object>` into png file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, save

How can I convert a `<tkinter,PhotoImage object>` into png file?
This is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

screen = tk.Tk()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 620
x, y = WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2
canvas = tk.Canvas(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()



def load_sprites(file_path, rows, cols):
    sprite_img = tk.PhotoImage(file=file_path)
    sprites = []
    height = sprite_img.height()//rows
    width = sprite_img.width()//cols
    for row in range(rows):
       for col in range(cols):
           l = col * width
           t = row*height
           r = (col+1)*width
           b = (row+1)*height
           subimage = create_subimage(sprite_img, l, t, r, b)
           sprites.append(subimage)
    return sprites

def create_subimage(img, left, top, right, bottom):
    subimage = tk.PhotoImage()
    subimage.tk.call(subimage, "copy", img, "-from", left, top, right, bottom, "-to",
                     0, 0)
    return subimage

sprite_list = load_sprites("sprites/__jet_pack_man_with_weapon_standing_idle.png", 3, 5)`
```

[<tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd69a2cb50>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd69a2caf0>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd699bc220>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd699bcfa0>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd699cc040>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd69a2cc10>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd699d9490>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd699d9f10>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd699e51c0>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd699f0250>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd699d9130>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd68d7b880>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd68d7b940>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd68d7ba30>, <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fbd68d7baf0>]

Comment: The `PhotoImage` class has a documented `write` method. Have you tried using it?

Comment: @Bryan: Where is this documented, please?

Comment: The canonical source of all tk widgets and functions are the tcl/tk man pages. I'm not sure where it's documented from a python perspective. [PhotoImage man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/photo.htm)

Comment: `python -c "import tkinter; help(tkinter.PhotoImage.write)"`.